# Hide an application from third party uninstallers

Tags: macos, third-party

Is there a way to hide an application from third party Uninstallers like MacKeeper?

I am using an application that blocks websites and everything else I want. When its blockers are running, I set it so that I can’t uninstall the application in the native way. But, third party Uninstallers like MacKeeper can easily uninstall the application without any problems.

So, I am wondering if there is a way to hide an application from third party Uninstallers.

Thank y’all.

Comment: Does mackeeper have a whitelist?

Comment: what if you install it under an admin account and then log in with a limited account with all restrictions turned on so you don't have the ability to uninstall anything. Is that moving in the direction of the solution you are looking for?

Comment: Hmmm I have to try it in few hours. I will get back to ya

Comment: I just tried it. And it won’t work. I grant access to every application that I have installed except for MacKeeper. I did this for a test, of course. But when I login to the limited account,, I get a. Pop-up on startup asking if I want to grant and allow MacKeeper to run or not...When this pop-up , it disables other applications to automatically start up, especially the application that I use to block websites and etc. For me, the blocking application is useless if it doesn’t automatically starts up.

Comment: I obviously can block every third party Uninstallers out there. But it would take me a week or longer since there are hundred upon hundreds of Uninstallers. I am disabled so everything I do is time consuming.

If there was a list of every exited Uninstallers, I would just copy and paste their window titles or application names (or even their process names) into the blocking application <-------- That would be easy!

Comment: I would suggest that it is good you can’t do this.  If you could then malware could stop themselves from being uninstalled. However what is the issue here makwarebytes is asking you if you want to delete so just say no. What other programs uninstall things.